# How to disable logging (except errors) in spring junit tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a `/src/test/resources/application.properties` with a simple `spring-boot` project:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.*=ERROR
```

Problem: during test runs, I still see the following output in console:

```
12:15:33.323 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
12:15:33.373 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
12:15:33.515 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [ServletITest] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper]
12:15:33.568 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.slr.hellodocker.HelloServletITest], using SpringBootContextLoader
12:15:33.576 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [ServletITest]: class path resource [ServletITest-context.xml] does not exist
12:15:33.579 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [ServletITest]: class path resource [ServletITestContext.groovy] does not exist
.....
```

How can I disable those boilerplate logging entirely (but not error logs)?

Comment: https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-test-how-to-stop-debug-logs/

Comment: remove `.*` from the logging config

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Creating a `/src/test/resources/logback.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You mean we can't use application.properties file from spring boot to achieve this?

Comment: @White_King at least I did not find a way without a logback configuration setting the logging level to eg `OFF` or `ERROR`. Feel free to comment if you find an alternative with application.properies!

Comment: I tried creating renaming logback-test.xml to logback.xml, modifying the application.yml, creating a boostrap.yml... nothing seems to work

Comment: That works for me, but a couple of `INFO`-level messages still slip through… only if i combine the above with an `application-test.yml` (or `.properties`-file) as described in https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-test-how-to-stop-debug-logs/ it works.

Answer (score 0):

Suppressing the logs consistently only works using a combination of `application[-test].[yml|properties]` and `logback[-test].xml`. The following solution is based on [Membersound's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59822248/1246547) and [this article](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-test-how-to-stop-debug-logs/) which was linked in one of the comments above.

The following setup using (1.) an application config file and (2.) a logback config file works for me to suppress everything except errors:

1. ##### `src/test/resources/application-test.yml`:

   ```yaml
   spring:
     main:
       banner-mode: "off"
   logging:
     level:
       org: "ERROR"
       root: "ERROR"
   ```

   For those of you not (yet) using yml config files, this is the equivalent

   ##### `application-test.properties`:

   ```
   spring.main.banner-mode=off
   logging.level.root=ERROR
   logging.level.org=ERROR
   ```
2. ##### `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml`

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
       <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
       <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
   </configuration>
   ```

---

One small explanation, in case you're wondering why the above application config does not mention `org.springboot` at all. The following (longer) yaml gives equivalent results in my project:

```yaml
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework: "ERROR"
      mongodb: "ERROR"
    root: "ERROR"
```

… because the project has a mongo db dependency, and without that specific log level value it still output's log messages coming from `org.mongodb.driver`. The shorter version at the top configures all logs under `org.*`.